# I'm working on a Metric Converter project for a class and I am not sure how to correctly use radio buttons?

Tags: javascript, html, radio-button

I'm working on a Metric Converter project for a class and I am supposed to use radio buttons but I'm not sure how I am supposed to use them correctly to call if statements I have for the conversion functions. My teacher is having me use javascript inside an html page. I'm not really sure as the IDE he's having us use it Netbeans and it doesn't work very well on mac, so I don't know if there are any syntax errors as Netbeans refuses to show half of them. I figure there is an easier way to do this but I can't find any info on how to use radio buttons like this on google. If there is a quick, easy way to fix it to work or if there is a better method of this, I'd love to know.

This is my code below:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>English to Metric Converter</title>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    </head>
    <body style="background-color: lightblue">
        <script type="text/javascript">
            var $ = function(id) {
                return document.getElementById(id);
            };
            function clrscrn() {
               $("convForm").reset();
               $("initval").focus();
            }
            window.onload = function() {
                $("clear").onclick = clrscrn;
                $("convert").onclick = convert;
            };
            function convert() {
                var initv = $("initval");
                var iv = parseFloat(initv.value);
                if (isNaN(iv)) {
                    alert("Please enter a numeric starting value.");
                    initv.focus();
                    return ;
                }
                alert("Input value validated as numeric: "+ iv);


            };

            function conversion() {
                 if (document.getElementById(id) === toC) {
                    double result = (initv – 32) * 5/9;
                    return ;

                }

                else if (document.getElementById(id) === toK) {
                    double result = initv * 1.6;
                    return ;
                }

                else if (getElementById(id) === toG) {
                    double result = initv * 28.35;
                    return ;
                }

                else {
                    alert("Please select a conversion");
                }
            }


        </script>
      <h1>English to Metric</h1>
          <p>Select the conversion and enter the English measurement you wish to convert:<br></p>
      <form name="convForm" id="convForm" action="" method="post">
          <p>Conversion type: <br ></p>
          <p>
          <input type="radio" id="toC" name="cType" value="toCelsius">Fahrenheit To Celsius<br>
          <input type="radio" id="toK" name="cType" value="toKilometers">Miles To Kilometers<br>
          <input type="radio" id="toG" name="cType" value="toGrams">Ounces To grams<br>
          <br ><br >
          <input type="text" id="initval" name="initval">
          <br ><br >
          <input type="button" id="convert" name="convert" value="Convert">
          <br ><br ></p>
          <p>Result: <br ></p>
          <input type ="text" id="result" name="result" style="width: 300px;">
          <br ><br >
          <input type="button" id="clear" name="clear" value="Clear">
      </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While I'm not completely sure of the issue you are having, it looks like you have the text you want next to the radio button just hanging out there in the file when you type:
"Fahrenheit to celsius"
"Miles to kilometers"
And 
"Ounces to grams"

This might be causing problems, as you don't want text just sitting in an html file with no wrapping like a

Look at this solution to add text next to your radio buttons!
[How to display text next to radio button?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10778323/how-to-display-text-next-to-radio-button)

(You should wrap in in a label, or float your text element to one side of the radio button)

Comment: In addition, your uses of <p> and <br> are very disorganized near your radio button code, which will make finding errors harder.